# How to use 'Decimal' as a field type in GraphQL schema?

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, apollo-server

I want to use `Decimal` as a type for latitude & longitude field in my GraphGL schema. But GraphQL provides only `Float` and `Int`.
Is there is any package to solve this?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Generally, questions asking for library recommendations are off-topic for SO. You could edit your question and ask how to write such a scalar yourself. That would be more appropriate for this site. However, it's also not totally clear what data you're trying to represent with such a scalar. Are you specifically targeting a database type, like postgres' decimal type? What are your requirements for this scalar?

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the reply. I updated the question.

Comment: Why would Float not satisfy your requirement? You have tagged node.js so the value would be handled as a Number, which is a 64 bit floating type?

Comment: Okay! Thanks for the confirmation. I thought that if there anything specific for Decimal.

Comment: I guess it depends on context. For example, a FLOAT/DOUBLE and a DECIMAL are definitely NOT the same in MySQL, a DECIMAL is not finite precision, it is an exact representation of a decimal number. See [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html). In fact, support for the Decimal type in python was added to the Graphene library, see [this PR](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/issues/703)

Answer (score 3):

I looked at the source code for [this module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-type-decimal) can came up with this:

```
///  I M P O R T

import Big from "big.js";
import { GraphQLScalarType, Kind } from "graphql";



///  E X P O R T

export default new GraphQLScalarType({
  name: "Decimal",
  description: "The `Decimal` scalar type to represent currency values",

  serialize(value) {
    return new Big(value);
  },

  parseLiteral(ast) {
    if (ast.kind !== Kind.STRING) {
      // @ts-ignore | TS2339
      throw new TypeError(`${String(ast.value)} is not a valid decimal value.`);
    }

    return Big(ast.value);
  },

  parseValue(value) {
    return Big(value);
  }
});
```

Then, I add the reference to my resolver so I can just add `Decimal` to my SDL code.